# Is translating system call enough to implement Linux compatibility layer of FreeBSD?

Tags: linux, freebsd

I am curious about mechanism of Linux compatibility layer of FreeBSD and got some info below.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeBSD#Compatibility_layers_with_other_operating_systems
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172038/what-allows-bsd-to-run-linux-binaries-but-not-vice-versa

The key difference between two OSes is difference of system calls.
And, I know Linux app and BSD app depend on different standard dynamic libraries (linux-gate.so.1 for example).

Is there anything else in the implementation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach to being able to run Linux apps in FreeBSD is multi-faceted.

The parts of the strategy, as I understand it, are as follows:

- Provide a system call layer that mimics as close as it can the Linux system call structure and semantics. In FreeBSD, this layer is called 'the linuxolator'
- Install a set of vanilla pre-compiled Linux userland libraries. These libraries work because the linuxolator provides the right system calls that they depend on.
- Install/provide/mount platform services that Linux userland libraries and apps expect. For example:

  - Mount a Linux-compatible procfs - linprocfs.
- Install pre-compiled Linux apps and have them depend on these Linux userland libraries.

The Linux Apps call the Linux libraries which call the Linuxolator's Linux system calls which call the FreeBSD system calls.

Answer (score 2):

Some functionality is available on Linux (`udev`, [systemd](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/), [inotify(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/inotify.7.html), ...) but not on FreeBSD (and probably vice versa).

Some system calls have different flags. FreeBSD [mmap(2)](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=mmap&sektion=2) is not exactly the same as Linux [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html), etc...

Both are Unix systems, but the devil is in the details.

If you want to code in C an application for both OSes, try hard to follow POSIX.

Comment: Note that "for both OSes, try hard to follow POSIX" has been good advice since POSIX has been around and "both OSes" were BSD 4.3 and Sys V.3.